# Not able to scrape the response from clicking on a Button using Python Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, request

Thank you all wonderful out there for reading this post and their help

For below URL, I have been trying to understand how to go about getting excel files which are downloaded after clicking on "Download Data" hyperlink. On inspecting this element, i get something like this "::before". Not sure what this is.

https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/find-fund/returns?&amc=AXMF&EXCLUDE_FIXED_MATURITY_PLANS=Y

I have downloaded files, in somewhat similar cases in the past, where such buttons contain URL directing to the file. I had to then make use of request library to get a bytes response which downloads the file in my local.

However, in this case, i am not able to find the URL to send response to.

[image: Button circled with Red color]

Cheers,

Aakash